# need assistance on installing i40e on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, system-installation

```
oot@vpre:~/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src# make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.o
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: In function â€˜i40e_get_netdev_stats_structâ€™:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:442:13: error: implicit declaration of function â€˜ACCESS_ONCEâ€™; did you mean â€˜READ_ONCEâ€™? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   tx_ring = ACCESS_ONCE(vsi->tx_rings[i]);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
             READ_ONCE
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:442:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   tx_ring = ACCESS_ONCE(vsi->tx_rings[i]);
           ^
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: In function â€˜i40e_update_vsi_statsâ€™:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:838:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   p = ACCESS_ONCE(vsi->tx_rings[q]);
     ^
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: At top level:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:5812:14: warning: â€˜struct tc_to_netdevâ€™ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
       struct tc_to_netdev *tc)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: In function â€˜__i40e_setup_tcâ€™:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:5818:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type â€˜struct tc_to_netdevâ€™
  if (tc->type != TC_SETUP_MQPRIO)
        ^~
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:5818:18: error: â€˜TC_SETUP_MQPRIOâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean â€˜TC_SETUP_BLOCKâ€™?
  if (tc->type != TC_SETUP_MQPRIO)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  TC_SETUP_BLOCK
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:5818:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: At top level:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:10158:19: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_setup_tc  = __i40e_setup_tc,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:10158:19: note: (near initialization for â€˜i40e_netdev_ops.ndo_setup_tcâ€™)
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: In function â€˜i40e_probeâ€™:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:12283:2: error: implicit declaration of function â€˜setup_timerâ€™; did you mean â€˜sk_stop_timerâ€™? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  setup_timer(&pf->service_timer, i40e_service_timer, (unsigned long)pf);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
  sk_stop_timer
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: In function â€˜i40e_removeâ€™:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:12628:23: error: â€˜struct timer_listâ€™ has no member named â€˜dataâ€™
  if (pf->service_timer.data)
                       ^
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c: In function â€˜__i40e_setup_tcâ€™:
/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.c:5828:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src/i40e_main.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/root/patch/i40e-2.2.4/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install an old version on a relatively new kernel version? I suggest that you try the latest version: 2.9.21: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24411/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-40-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-

Comment: At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.15.0-54-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
/sbin/depmod -e -F /boot/System.map-4.15.0-54-generic  -a 4.15.0-54-generic
Updating initramfs...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic

Comment: im getting error with SSL

Comment: I don't think this prevents the module from being built and installable. Did you follow with `sudo make install` And did it install? `sudo modprobe i40e`

Comment: I did make install and then rmmod i40e;  modprobe i40e but the command kept loading it never went back prompt

Comment: What do the logs report? `dmesg | grep i40e`